# Can the opencensus stats python stackdriver exporter be used in the python 2 app engine standard environment?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, opencensus

[In the docs](https://opencensus.io/quickstart/python/metrics/#installation) it says to install a cloud client library (pip install google-cloud-monitoring). However the cloud client libraries aren't available in the python2 standard environment on app engine, [described here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/python-differences#cloud_client_libraries).

To use the stackdriver exporter, do you have to be using the beta python 3 runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is only available in the new Python 3.7 runtime.